# Добавление объекта при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: android, activity, android-button

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на одну кнопку на одном Activity, появлялся объект на другом Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю что вам нужно копать в сторону динамического добавления виджетов на `layout`. В чем суть: у вас на одной активити висит кнопка, при нажатии на которую вы должны передавать на другое какое-то значение и дальше стартовать новую активити. А уже на новой активити получать эту переменную, и дальше программно добавлять виджет. Вот как вы можете добавлять виджет (в данном примере вы можете добавить `ImageView` но суть должна быть понятна) на активити:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
        
// Добавляем новый ImageView
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
  
mainLayout.addView(imageView);
}
```

Вот по [этой](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/addview.php) ссылке вы можете ознакомится с первоисточником.

### UPDATE

В вашей главной активити у вас есть кнопка и слушатель, при нажатии на кнопку вам нужно будет переходить на другое активити, где уже будет добавлен `imageView`. Вот как мы будем это делать:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A_activty, B_activity.class); 
intent.putInt("value", какое-то число);

Intent intent2 = new Intent(A_activty, С_activity.class); // переход на вашу активити  C

startActivity(intent2 )
```

дальше на вашей второй активити вам нужно получать эту отправленную переменную:

```
Integer value = getIntent().getIntExtra("value", значение по-умолчанию);
```

дальше вы делаете проверку, например что если приходящая переменная равна 1, то значит добавляем один виджет, если 2 то другой.

Надеюсь хоть чем-то помог. Удачи:)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83338/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-goroshko------).